# Functional components in React that run only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state, react-functional-component

I was trying to create a grid in React and got really confused when my program gave me different outputs depending on whether I save the file in my editor or refresh the page on the live server.

Afaik the `useEffect()` hook runs only once if you pass it an empty array, `[]`, as the second parameter. However, when I run my code:

```
  const [grid, setGrid] = useState([]);
  console.log(grid);

  useEffect(() => {
      const grid = [];
      for (let row = 0; row < 15; row++) {
          const currentRow = [];
          for (let node = 0; node < 40; node++) {
              currentRow.push(createNode(node, row));
          }
          grid.push(currentRow);
      }
      setGrid(grid);
  }, []);
```

The console logs two (I'm not 100% sure why it `console.log` twice but alas) arrays with a total of 600 `createNode(node, row)` objects, which is what I want! And if I edit the code and save it also displays this. My problem is that if I refresh the live server the console spits out an empty array, `[]`, on the first `console.log` and then it logs the array of 600 objects.

I have other functionality in my program that uses the `grid` array but I'm pretty sure these break because they are passed an empty array. At least I get an error "cannot read property 'x' of undefined" when I manually refresh the page compared to when I just save in the editor.

Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated...

EDIT:
The grid renders just fine but as soon as I import my logic for Dijkstra's algorithm

```
import dijkstra from "./algorithms/dijkstra";
```

Then I call the function

```
dijkstra(grid, grid[7][10])
```

which is only partly implemented but still:

```
function dijkstra(grid, startNode) {
    const unvisitedNodes = getNodes(grid);
    startNode.distance = 0;
    sortByDistance(unvisitedNodes);
    const closestNode = unvisitedNodes.shift();
    console.log(getNeighbors(closestNode, grid));
}

function sortByDistance(nodes) {
    nodes.sort((nodeA, nodeB) => nodeA.distance - nodeB.distance);
}

function getNodes(grid) {
    const unvisitedNodes = [];
    for (const row of grid) {
        for (const node of row) {
            unvisitedNodes.push(node);
        }
    }
    return unvisitedNodes;
}

function getNeighbors(referenceNode, grid) {
    const neighbors = [];
    const { row, col } = referenceNode;
    if (row > 0) neighbors.push(grid[row + 1][col]);
    if (row < grid.length - 1) neighbors.push(grid[row - 1][col]);
    if (col > 0) neighbors.push(grid[row][col - 1]);
    if (col < grid[0].length - 1) neighbors.push(grid[row][col + 1]);
    return neighbors;
}

export default dijkstra;
```

Comment: If you render the grid does it output the elements correctly?

Comment: It renders the grid just fine but as soon as I add functionality from a different file (namely for dijkstra's algorithm) the program breaks as soon as I manually refresh the page (but not if I save in the editor) @Syder

Comment: maybe the problem is how you use the state with those other files, can you add that code to your question?

Comment: @Syder I added more of the code!

Comment: dijkstra(grid, grid[7][10]) => where are you calling this? i think the problem is that that function is called on the first render, when the grid isn't defined yet

Comment: I call it right after the useEffect hook before the return statement.

Comment: you can try move it inside another useEffect hook, like: useEffect(()=>{if(grid !== []){dijkstra(grid, grid[7][10])}}, [grid])

Answer (score 0):

yes that's how **React** works. Whenever you refresh your browser the app renders. In React render

1. At first, states are initialized (that's why your 1st console log was empty array)
2. then DOM prints
3. then lifecycle methods or hooks are initialized
4. then DOM again prints with updated state.(that's why you have the objects in 2nd log)
   the whole process repeats when you reload your browser.

`[]` in `useEffect` prevents re-run of the hook when you update your states only.

Comment: I can render my grid just fine, but as soon as I import another file with logic for dijkstra's algorithm the program breaks as soon as I manually refresh the page. This is where I get the error "cannot read property 'x' of undefined". Do note that it all works as intended if I just save from the editor but not with page refreshes...

Comment: Care to explain why the console.log returns different things on refresh page / editor save?  I can't really wrap my head around it if "the whole process repeats" when I reload my browser

Comment: i think that happens because hot reloading is preserving your state on editor save